# Play Framework 2.3 no resources after migration

Tags: resources, playframework-2.3

I have a play framework 2.1 application. This app worked. Then I migrated to 2.2, tested it and it worked. Now I am migrating to 2.3 and I got an error like:

```
[debug] application - Unforseen error for favicon.svg at /public
java.lang.RuntimeException: no resource
at controllers.Assets$$anonfun$controllers$Assets$$assetInfoFromResource$1$$anonfun$13.apply(Assets.scala:237) ~[na:na]
at controllers.Assets$$anonfun$controllers$Assets$$assetInfoFromResource$1$$anonfun$13.apply(Assets.scala:237) ~[na:na]
at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120) [na:na]
at controllers.Assets$$anonfun$controllers$Assets$$assetInfoFromResource$1.apply(Assets.scala:237) ~[na:na]
at controllers.Assets$$anonfun$controllers$Assets$$assetInfoFromResource$1.apply(Assets.scala:236) ~[na:na]
```

There is a /public folder, but all resources are resulting in above error. The app serves such resources as 404 Not Found.

**Any help would be great. Some cleaning procecese, cached files I can delete, redownload dependencies or maybe I have a wrong configuration.**

Here are some config files I have for better understanding:
build.sbt:

```
import com.typesafe.sbt.less.Import.LessKeys import play.PlayJava

name := """blabla-de"""

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava)

scalaVersion := "2.11.1"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(   filters,   cache,   javaCore,   javaWs, javaJdbc,   javaEbean,   "org.webjars" % "bootstrap" % "3.0.0",   "org.webjars" % "rjs" % "2.1.11-1-trireme" % "test",   "org.webjars" % "squirejs" % "0.1.0" % "test",   "junit" % "junit" % "4.11" % "test" )


testOptions += Tests.Argument(TestFrameworks.JUnit, "-v")

LessKeys.compress in Assets := true

includeFilter in (Assets, LessKeys.less) := "*.less"

excludeFilter in (Assets, LessKeys.less) := "_*.less"

pipelineStages := Seq(rjs, digest, gzip)
```

conf/routes:

```
# Home page
GET     /                           controllers.Index.index()

GET     /about                      controllers.About.index()

## Contact Page
GET     /contact                    controllers.Contact.index()
POST    /contact                    controllers.Contact.newContact()

## Gallery List
GET     /portfolio                  controllers.Portfolio.index()

## Text(HTML) Page
GET     /impressum                  controllers.Impressum.index()
#GET     /legal
GET     /privacy                    controllers.Privacy.index()

# Map static resources from the /public folder to the / URL path
GET    /*file               controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
```

project/build.properties:

```
sbt.version=0.13.5
```

project/plugins.sbt:

```
// Comment to get more information during initialization
logLevel := Level.Warn

// The Typesafe repository 
resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

// The Play plugin
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.3.1")

// web plugins
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.3.1")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-less" % "1.0.0")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-coffeescript" % "1.0.0")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-rjs" % "1.0.1")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-digest" % "1.0.0")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-gzip" % "1.0.0")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-mocha" % "1.0.0")
```

Thank You in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is in the migration guide: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/Migration23

> The largest new feature for Play 2.3 is the introduction of sbt-web.
>   In summary sbt-web allows Html, CSS and JavaScript functionality to be
>   factored out of Play’s core into a family of pure sbt plugins.

Unavailability of public resources must be caused by improper configuration of sbt-web.

What I can see immediately is that you forgot to enable SbtWeb plugins. Here is another quote from the migration guide:

> declaring addSbtPlugin may not be sufficient for plugins that now
>   utilize to the auto plugin functionality.

So you need to fix the following line in your build.sbt:

```
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava, SbtWeb)
```

Comment: Thank you.
I deleted the line `// web plugins
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.3.1")` in project/plugins.sbt , which was duplicate.
Then I updated the version from 2.3.1 to 2.3.3.
By enabling the "auto plugins" feature it works now as expected.

Comment: Why not to update to the latest bugfix release that is 2.3.4?

Comment: @lagivan I'm not sure what bugfix you're talking about, but I just came here to fix a 2.2.1 to 2.3.4 migration. Thanks for the help! Beat my head against the desk for a couple hours on this one.